# Rack-mount Server With 1U

Tags: rack

Rack-mount Server with 1U

What is `1U` ?

Answer (score 19):

1U stands for one "rack unit", which is 1.75 inches high. Rack-mounted equipment's height is generally an exact multiple of one unit to make the amount of rack space used highly efficient.